# With template deduction, std::vector<int&> is feasible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pass-by-reference

I am learning C++ and now proceeding the reference collapsing stuff.
However I have a doubt now:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& Foo(T) // value of parameter is unnecessary
{
    static std::vector<T> s_vec_T;
    return s_vec_T;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    auto get_vec = Foo(i); // suppose Foo() would be Foo<int&>(i)

    return 0;
}
```

So in the end, the static vector in `Foo()` `s_vec_T` would be instantiated as `std::vector<int&>`. 
Nonetheless, the code runs well. Why? There is nothing reference collapsing to deal with I suppose.

Comment: `T` is deduced as `int`, not `int&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` would be deduced as `int` (`i` is `int` so that's the type that will be deduced) so there's no problem there. `std::vector` can't hold references so if it somehow deduced it as `int&` it might not even compile.

Comment: So in what kind of situation that `T` would be deduced as int&?

Comment: @AhSengFan That sounds like a decent question to ask.  Try searching for it first, and if you cannot find the solution, ask a question on SO!

Comment: In `template <typename T> std::vector<T>& Foo(T&& x)` if you pass a `lvalue`.

Comment: @vsoftco So can I conlcude that with the plain template argument `T` in function parameter, in this case, `Foo()`, T will always be deduced as normal value type instead of reference type?

Comment: @AhSengFan Yes, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction for more details. References and CV qualifiers are stripped away.